# How to change the loading order of styles in NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to override the loading order of styles in my project.

I have created my stylesheet `style.css` in which I have overridden the defaults,

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

At the same time in the project I have ***bootstrapVue*** connected for use through the plugin,

```
import Vue from "vue";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
```

Due to the fact that I only use a subset of the overridden styles, I would like to use the rest of the styles from the bootstrap.

However when I run the project I see the bootstrap style comes first and not mine,

****_reboot.scss** :**

```
body { 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}

style.css - disabled (I dont know how to show that the text is crossed out, without loading a picture)
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

How can this be changed without specifying styles in the `<style>` section in ***/pages/layout.vue***?

Comment: into where are you importing style.css?

Comment: in nyxt.config.js:  css: ["@/assets/css/style.css"],  plugins: ["@/plugins/bootstrapVue"],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap Vue has its own Nuxt module so you don't need to create your own custom plugin. Using the module, you can [disable Bootstrap Vue's automatic importing of styles](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#using-custom-bootstrap-scss) and then `@import` those styles directly into your `style.css` before you declare your own stuff, so that your changes override Bootstrap Vue's. Or, you could import the SCSS versions instead and make your changes [using SCSS variables](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/theming). If you want to stick with your own custom plugin, just take the CSS imports out of your plugin and put them in your `style.css` as below and ignore the `nuxt.config.js` stuff.

```css
/* style.css */

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.css';
@import '../node_modules/vue-bootstrap/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

body {
  ...
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt'],
  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false
  }
}
```